# Array merge while keeping the same order?

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array that is an array of arrays, ordered by date, as so:

```
Array
(
    [1379167200] => Array
        (
            [110] => Introduction to Banking | Saturday, September 14, 2013 - 10:00am
        )

    [1380376800] => Array
        (
            [71] => Saving, Investing, Debt | Saturday, September 28, 2013 - 10:00am
        )

    [1381588200] => Array
        (
            [72] => Setting Personal Goals | Saturday, October 12, 2013 - 10:30am
        )

    [1382796000] => Array
        (
            [74] => Type of Account: What's Right for You? | Saturday, October 26, 2013 - 10:00am
        )

    [1384009200] => Array
        (
            [81] => Creating an Account: Learning to Budget | Saturday, November 09, 2013 - 10:00am
        )
)
```

I want to keep the ordering (i.e., ordered by date), but preferably only include the most inner array items in a single array. Like so:

```
Array
(
        [110] => Introduction to Banking | Saturday, September 14, 2013 - 10:00am

        [71] => Saving, Investing, Debt | Saturday, September 28, 2013 - 10:00am

        [72] => Setting Personal Goals | Saturday, October 12, 2013 - 10:30am

        [74] => Type of Account: What's Right for You? | Saturday, October 26, 2013 - 10:00am

        [81] => Creating an Account: Learning to Budget | Saturday, November 09, 2013 - 10:00am
)
```

How would this be possible? Would I need to convert the integers to strings or something?

I absolutely need to maintain the ordering by date, but I also need to maintain the relationship between the integer key and the value, both are used.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through array, create new array:

```
$newArray = Array();
foreach($array as $row) { // $row is subarray
   $value = current($row); // first value in subarray "Itroduction to ..."
   $key = key($row); // first key in subarray 101, 71, 72
   $newArray[$key] = $value;
}
```

Demo;

- http://codepad.viper-7.com/dd3PLV

Docs:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php